# How can i make infinite flowing background with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm just started to web programming, cuz many cooooool pages on awwwards.com - definitely caught my mind.

anyway, the first page what i aim for make is the pinterest (www.pinterest.com); **slowly moving background** with blur effect, floating modal and bottom fixed footer.

with some kinda O'Reilly books, the blur, modal and footer are no more problem. but i couldn't made the background even with them yet.

so, how can i make **horizontally infinite flowing background with only CSS**??? (without JS)

*conditions

1. the page is responsive, background-image's height should fit to screen
2. width follow the height's size, as original image's ratio.

and here's my code.

```html
  <head>
     <style type="text/css">
     * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     }
     html {
      height: 100%;
     }
     body {
      overflow: hidden;
     }
     #animatedBackground {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: url("http://placehold.it/1600x800");
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-size: auto 100%;

   border: 1px solid red;

      animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
     }
     @keyframes animatedBackground {
      from {
       left: -50%;
      }
      to {
       left: 50%;
      }
     }
     </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div id="animatedBackground">animatedBackground</div>
    </body>
```

thx.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should fit your slowly moving+infinite flowing+responsively fit to height background criteria.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#animatedBackground {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("http://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/238/63bb30c8-2649-465e-9df1-ab2f8e5f7ecc.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
/*adjust s value for speed*/
  animation: animatedBackground 500s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
/*use negative width if you want it to flow right to left else and positive for left to right*/
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animatedBackground">
</div>
```

Comment: nice. this is what i want to know about. thank you. but a little problem, when the animation re-starts i can see the image's delay. can you solve it also? cuz image that i using is not pattern so i want make flow it really smoothly. thx.

Comment: If you change keyframes animatedBackground { to { background-position: 100% 0; } to something negative to its width such as animatedBackground { to { background-position: -1800px 0; } this should solve it. I am accessing the site on my mobile phone at the moment so it is a bit hard for me to test it, please try it out yourself.

Comment: @schichinen use negative width if you want it to flow right to left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-attachment:scroll` and use `keyframes` to perform the animation. See my approach here:

**CSS**

```css
html,body
    {
      background:url("http://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/238/63bb30c8-2649-465e-9df1-ab2f8e5f7ecc.jpg");
      background-repeat:repeat;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes slideshow
    {
      0% {top:0;}
      100% {top:-200%;}
      
    }
```

**See here**:   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr5mctdn/1/)

Comment: This will move the whole page up and down again and again..is this what he is looking for?

Comment: thank you for your answer, that looks similar with result which i want, but different with it.

Comment: Hey man, its not an answer, actually in support of the @shichinen , I'm also trying this trick, and want this in to the div tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```html
<html>
 <head>
     <style type="text/css">
     #animatedBackground {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: url("http://placehold.it/1600x800");
            animation:5s scroll infinite linear;
   border: 1px solid red;
   
     }
     @keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:-3000px 0px;
  }
}
     </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div id="animatedBackground" style="text-align:center;">animatedBackground</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: your solution creates a vertical scrollbar